# MySQL: IF statement used with SUM

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
Unique | Common |  Score
1      |   1    |   10  
2      |   1    |   10  
3      |   1    |   10
4      |   1    |   -10
```

If I run this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(`score`) AS `total`
FROM
    `test`
GROUP BY
    `common`
```

I get the total:

```
20
```

This is what I'd expect.

I want to treat negative numbers as zero and sum the remaining score to get a total. So, if I run this:

```
SELECT
    IF(`score`<0, 0, SUM(`score`)) AS `total`
FROM
    `myTable`
GROUP BY
    `unique`
```

I get these totals:

```
10
10
10
0
```

This is what I'd expect as well.

But, If I run this:

```
SELECT
    IF(`score`<0, 0, SUM(`score`)) AS `total`
FROM
    `myTable`
GROUP BY
    `common`
```

I get a total of:

```
20
```

Why do I get 20 instead of 30 when performing the last query? The only difference is the grouping.

BTW, removing the superflous `Group by` clause from the last query also gives a result of 20.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because it's doing 10+10+10+(-10), which is 20.

Comment: If you want to treat negative numbers as zero do you still want to have rows < 0 in the result set?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 SELECT
    SUM(`score`) AS `total`
FROM
 `myTable` WHERE score > 0
GROUP BY
 `common`
```

Comment: This query delivers the right result if records with score `<= 0` can be filtered out of the result set.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this but I think you have your IF and SUM the wrong way round. I think it should be like this

```
SELECT
  SUM( IF(`score`<0, 0,`score`) ) AS `total`
FROM
  `myTable`
GROUP BY
  `common`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT
    SUM( IF(`score`<0, 0, score))  AS `total`
FROM
    `myTable`
GROUP BY
    `common`
```